# What is the best way to show SSRS 2008r2 reports in a remote web (access and security)

Tags: asp-classic, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I made some reports using SSRS and now I need to access them from a web site in another server. I'm new to SSRS and I would like to know the best way to do this.

This is my network structure, and my progress so far:

1.SERVER01 has the web site (which was coded using classic ASP).
2.The SSRS is in SERVER02 (which is running SQL Server 2008 R2).
3.SERVER02 also has several databases, identical in structure, but each one belonging to a different customer.
4.In the web site (on SERVER01) I have a page with an hyperlink to each report.
5.When I am login to my web site from a PC on my local network and I click on one of the report links, SERVER02 (the SSRS server) asks for my (Windows) username and password. After I enter them, I see the report and all works good.
6.But my customers are not on my local network, they login to the web site on SERVER01 via the internet.
7.When a customer logs in, a couple of session variables are filled with his user id and his target-database (each customer is able to access all reports, but can connect only to his database, so all the reports accept the target database name as a parameter).
8.But when they click on the report-link, they are also presented with the dialog to enter a username and password.

Some questions:

1.How do I configure my reports so my customers (who already logged in to my web site) can access them without being asked for another username/password (which they don’t have).
2.Is there a better way of passing the target-database parameter? Right now it is part of the report’s URL. Maybe pass the session variable to the report and make a function that select database using the session values? Is it possible? It can affect the performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For both question 1 & 2 the answer is that it's possible, but in both cases, you'd need to undertake some custom web development to extend SSRS functionality.

Comment: Do you mean to add in the website or inside the report? And how should I search information about it?